# Forcing a newline in the algpseudocode package

Tags: line-breaking, algorithmicx

I have written the following pseudocode:

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Check if any player has won.}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Procedure{isWin}{$Game$}
\ForAll{$seq \in \Call{getWinSeqs}{Game}$}
  \For{$i \gets 0, length(seq) - 1$}
    \If{$\not seq[i] = seq[i + 1]$}
      break
    \EndIf
  \EndFor
  \If{$seq[i + 1] = `X'$}
    \Return `X'
  \ElsIf{$seq[i + 1] = `O'$}
    \Return `O'
  \EndIf
\EndFor
\Return null
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

which renders to the following image:

[image: rendering of algorithm]

As seen in the image, the final `return` is placed directly after `end for`. How can I force a newline after `return`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `algpseudocode` rather than `algorithmicx`; redefine `\algorithmicreturn` to issue `\State`

I've also made some refinements to your code. Note, in particular, that the negation symbol is `\lnot`, while `\not` is a different command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\newcommand{\var}[1]{\mathit{#1}}
\newcommand{\qt}[1]{\mbox{`#1'}}
\algrenewcommand{\algorithmicreturn}{\State \textbf{return}}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]            
\Procedure{isWin}{$\var{Game}$}
\ForAll{$\var{seq} \in \Call{getWinSeqs}{\var{Game}}$}
  \For{$i \gets 0, \mathrm{length}(\var{seq}) - 1$}
    \If{$\lnot \var{seq}[i] = \var{seq}[i + 1]$}
      break
    \EndIf
  \EndFor
  \If{$\var{seq}[i + 1] = \qt{X}$}
    \Return $\qt{X}$
  \ElsIf{$seq[i + 1] = \qt{O}$}
    \Return $\qt{O}$
  \EndIf
\EndFor
\Return null
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf - as per the documentation, the command set `algpsuedocode` is defined in there. Thanks for the improvements made; could you also explain what `\var` and `\qt` is for?

Comment: @wei2912 A multiletter variable like *seq* shouldn't be typed just so in math mode, because the spacing would be wrong, so it's better to use `\mathit` around it and even better using a macro resolving to `\mathit`. I used `\qt` for denoting a quoted string.